# Print the Twelve Days of Christmas without loops or conditionals

Tags: java, recursion

For my AP Computer Science class, I am required to write a program that prints the Twelve Days of Christmas without loops or conditionals using static methods.

```
public class TwelveDaysOfChristmas {

    public static final String[] lines = new String[] {
        "A partridge in a pear tree",
        "Two turtle doves and",
        "Three French Hens,",
        "Four calling birds",
        "Five golden rings.",
        "Six geese a-laying,",
        "Seven swans a-swimming,",
        "Eight maids a-milking,",
        "Nine ladies dancing,",
        "Ten lords a-leaping,",
        "Eleven Pipers piping,",
        "Twelve drummers drumming,"
    };

    public static final String[] days = new String[] {
        "first",
        "second",
        "third",
        "fourth",
        "fifth",
        "sixth",
        "seventh",
        "eighth",
        "ninth",
        "tenth",
        "eleventh",
        "twelfth"
    };

    public static final String verseText =
        "On the %s day of Christmas,\n" +
        "My true love sent to me\n" +
        "%s";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Print the song
        System.out.println(song());
    }

    public static String song() {
        //The song consists of all verses up to verse 12, but the index starts from 0
        //Print verses 0 to 11
        return versesBelow(11);
    }

    public static String versesBelow(int verse) {
        //Evil hack that allows me to check whether the input is zero without using a conditional ;)
        try {
            //Divide by verse. If the verse is zero, then an ArithmeticException is thrown.
            //I am not using a conditional here!!!
            int i = 1 / verse;
        }
        catch(ArithmeticException ex) {
            //Stop the recursion
            return verse(verse);
        }
        //else return this verse and all the verses below this one.
        return versesBelow(verse - 1) + verse(verse);
    }

    public static String verse(int verse) {
        //Format the string with the correct day and verse and add a newline for a blank space after
        return String.format(verseText, days[verse], linesBelow(verse)) + '\n';
    }

    public static String linesBelow(int line) {
        //Same evil hack
        try {
            int i = 1 / line;
        }
        catch(ArithmeticException ex) {
            //Stop the recursion if line is zero
            return line(line);
        }
        //Else return this line and all the lines below this line
        return line(line) + linesBelow(line - 1);
    }

    public static String line(int line) {
        //Return this line and a newline
        return lines[line] + '\n';
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to accomplish this than my way? I do kind of cheat a little, but it's not technically a conditional, is it?

Comment: What's wrong with just printing the lyrics literally then, with these restrictions?

Comment: @h.j.k. The assignment is worded such that it's not possible to just do that.

Comment: I think there might be an slight extra issue to consider: as far as I remember the first verse goes: "On the first day of Christmas my true love sent to me a partridge in a pear tree." but the second and all subsequent verses end with:
"*AND* a partridge in a pear tree" ie there's an extra "and" before the last line in verses 2-12 inclusive. Tricky without any conditionals though! Just in case it helps make the solution complete...

Comment: @BruceLamond The OP has solved this problem by putting the word "and" at the end of the second-to-last line.

Comment: It crushes my soul to see assignments like this, asking students to do useless things in roundabout and arcane ways.

Comment: @Aurast I'd rather have my teacher assign one big assignment per chapter with useful applications of the chapters' contents as well

Comment: http://udel.edu/~mm/xmas/ :)

Comment: I feel like a try/catch is technically still a conditional.  Basically "If this generates an exception, do this instead".  Still a condition.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman I actually considered that as well, but I'll just have to see what my teacher says about it.

Comment: Pointless tripe. I for one certainly don't miss it. The real world is better, so just hang in there!

Comment: @nmission: [Kobayashi Maru](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kobayashi_Maru)

Comment: @ZigMandel - Horrifying, though it wouldn't qualify for this question due to extensive use of `?:` operators.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Recursion is something that is often "unwrapped" to become loops, but the same is true, in the other direction. Almost all loops can be implemented as recursion.

Using your "trick" of throwing an exception to act as a conditional, it would be simple to turn all your code... this code:

> ```
> public static final String verseText =
>     "On the %s day of Christmas,\n" +
>     "My true love sent to me\n" +
>     "%s";
>
> public static void main(String[] args) {
>     //Print the song
>     System.out.println(song());
> }
>
> public static String song() {
>     //The song consists of all verses up to verse 12, but the index starts from 0
>     //Print verses 0 to 11
>     return versesBelow(11);
> }
>
> public static String versesBelow(int verse) {
>     //Evil hack that allows me to check whether the input is zero without using a conditional ;)
>     try {
>         //Divide by verse. If the verse is zero, then an ArithmeticException is thrown.
>         //I am not using a conditional here!!!
>         int i = 1 / verse;
>     }
>     catch(ArithmeticException ex) {
>         //Stop the recursion
>         return verse(verse);
>     }
>     //else return this verse and all the verses below this one.
>     return versesBelow(verse - 1) + verse(verse);
> }
>
> public static String verse(int verse) {
>     //Format the string with the correct day and verse and add a newline for a blank space after
>     return String.format(verseText, days[verse], linesBelow(verse)) + '\n';
> }
>
> public static String linesBelow(int line) {
>     //Same evil hack
>     try {
>         int i = 1 / line;
>     }
>     catch(ArithmeticException ex) {
>         //Stop the recursion if line is zero
>         return line(line);
>     }
>     //Else return this line and all the lines below this line
>     return line(line) + linesBelow(line - 1);
> }
>
> public static String line(int line) {
>     //Return this line and a newline
>     return lines[line] + '\n';
> }
> ```

in to just:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        recurseDown(0);
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        // nothing.
    }
}

private static void recurseDown(int i) {
    System.out.println("\nOn the " + days[i] + " day of Christmas\nMy true love sent to me");
    try {
        recurseUp(i);
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        // nothing.
    }
    recurseDown(i + 1);
}

private static void recurseUp(int i) {
    System.out.println(lines[i]);
    recurseUp(i - 1);
}
```

you can see it running here: http://ideone.com/SAte6Z

Written properly, it would be:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    recurseDown(0);
}

private static void recurseDown(int i) {
    if (i == days.length) {
        return;
    }
    System.out.println("\nOn the " + days[i] + " day of Christmas\nMy true love sent to me");
    recurseUp(i);

    recurseDown(i + 1);
}

private static void recurseUp(int i) {
    if (i < 0) { 
        return;
    }
    System.out.println(lines[i]);
    recurseUp(i - 1);
}
```

Comment: Loops are a subset of recursion, so all loops can be implemented with recursion.

Comment: @bjb568 Not true, an endless while loop comes to mind. Trying to make an infinite loop through recursion instead of a regular loop **will** cause a stack overflow.

Comment: @Kevin It depends on whether your language will support an infinite stack then :p

Comment: I guess that's a question for "Stack Overflow" ... kidding, but languages with support for tail recursion will do it... but this is Java.

Comment: @bjb568 Infinite stacks come with hardware requirements (infinite storage, preferably in RAM), which are not realistically available. Loops have the possibility to run forever without ever changing the stack, you can't do this with recursion. Therefore, loops are **not** a subset of recursion.

Comment: Compilers could theoretically optimize an infinite recursion loop to the equivalent of a while loop. If the function doesn't return or if the result isn't used its caller wouldn't need to be on the stack.

Answer (score 15):

> I am required to write a program that prints the Twelve Days of Christmas without loops or conditionals...

Usually, that's code for using `try-catch` to purposefully let parts of your code fail (e.g. when determining an array index), and then *remediate* that in the `catch`. Makes for a 'fun' academic exercise such as this, just bear in mind this should *strictly* be only for fun, and not for writing clean, quality code. :)

## Commenting and hard-coding

```
public static String song() {
    //The song consists of all verses up to verse 12, but the index starts from 0
    //Print verses 0 to 11
    return versesBelow(11);
}
```

This comment is redundant as it does not say anything more than what the code is plainly doing, but more importantly, `11` is hard-coded here. Since you already have an array, you can do something like `array.length - 1` here so that it's easier for you to add extra lines in the future (e.g. 365 days of Christmas for non-leap-years).

## Code duplication

Your `versesBelow()` and `linesBelow()` methods are very similar, so you may want to consider doing some de-duplication here by generalizing the problem...

```
// Function<T, R> is a Java 8 feature
private static generate(int x, Function<Integer, String> function, 
                            String before, String after) {
    String previous;
    try {
        int i = 1 / x;
        previous = function.apply(x- 1);
    }
    catch(ArithmeticException ex) {
        previous = "";
    }
    return before + previous + after;
}
```

- We know we need to append the output from the previous day, except for the first.
- Using a `previous` placeholder, `try` to perform our 'stop condition'. If we `catch` the expected `Exception`, it means we can concatenate with `""`.
- We need `before` and `after` here as both methods require the previous output to be concatenated differently.

The two methods can then be refactored as such (using [method references](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html)):

```
// Changed visibility modifier to private
private static String versesBelow(int verse) {
    return generate(verse, TwelveDaysOfChristmas::versesBelow, "", verse(verse));
}

private static String linesBelow(int line) {
    return generate(line, TwelveDaysOfChristmas::linesBelow, line(line), "");
}
```

## Alternate modeling

When you have two *enumerated* `String[]` arrays where there's a close relationship between one and the other, you can consider representing them as an [`enum`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html). This lets you reference one value with the other, almost like a `key-value` relationship. For example:

```
enum Day {
    FIRST("A partridge in a pear tree."),
    SECOND("Two turtle doves and"),
    THIRD("Three French hens,"),
    FOURTH("Four calling birds,"),
    FIFTH("Five golden rings!"),
    SIXTH("Six geese a-laying,"),
    SEVENTH("Seven swans a-swimming,"),
    EIGHTH("Eight maids a-milking,"),
    NINETH("Nine ladies dancing,"),
    TENTH("Ten lords a-leaping,"),
    ELEVENTH("Eleven Pipers piping,"),
    TWELFTH("Twelve drummers drumming,");

    private final String line;

    private Day(String line) {
        this.line = line;
    }
}
```

## Generating verses

With the `enum` in place, we now need to generate the verse for each `Day`. Since an `enum` is also a class, we can conveniently override its [`toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#toString--) for a [*more 'programmer-friendly' form*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#toString--).

```
enum Day {
    // ...

    private String getVerse() {
        String next;
        try {
            next = values()[ordinal() - 1].getVerse();
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            next = "";
        }
        return String.format("%s%n%s", line, next);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("On the %s day of Christmas, my true love gave to me,%n%s",
                name().toLowerCase(), getVerse());
    }
}
```

Instead of `catch`-ing for an `ArithmeticException`, we can just handle for the case where `ordinal() - 1` gives us `-1`, a special case *only* for the first day.

## Look ma, no loops

> What's wrong with just printing the lyrics literally then, with these restrictions? - [*myself*](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/113328/print-the-twelve-days-of-christmas-without-loops-or-conditionals#comment209680_113328)

I meant that partly in-jest, but if we really need to avoid any loops, we can also call each `enum` value one-by-one to print them:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(Day.FIRST);
    System.out.println(Day.SECOND);
    System.out.println(Day.THIRD);
    System.out.println(Day.FOURTH);
    System.out.println(Day.FIFTH);
    System.out.println(Day.SIXTH);
    System.out.println(Day.SEVENTH);
    System.out.println(Day.EIGHTH);
    System.out.println(Day.NINETH);
    System.out.println(Day.TENTH);
    System.out.println(Day.ELEVENTH);
    System.out.println(Day.TWELFTH);
}
```

Comment: You could further reduce your main method to a recursive call that uses the iterator of Day.values() ;-)

Comment: @Aron_dc of course, I simply picked that to showcase a *literal* implementation. :D

Comment: Your suggestions are good, and I would normally do that, but part of the requirement was that you use static methods and I can't use Java 8 features :)

Answer (score 10):

Update: I've removed the Java 8 stuff, and I can't remember if Generics were in Java 5 or not, so they went as well. Hopefully this will work with that compiler.

The logic for this solution relies on two concepts, bitwise conditionals, and lazy evaluation. Additionally we'll throw in some nice abstractions to help make things a bit nicer.

### Lazy Evaluation

A big part of recursion in functional languages is lazy evaluation. Basically we give code that we don't want to execute just yet (or possibly never). Java doesn't have this built in, but we can fake it.

We'll have to declare some interfaces to accomplish this, but they are pretty straightforward.

Assuming we have this interface:

```
private interface LazyOperation {
    String apply ();
}
```

We can do this:

```
LazyOperation op = new LazyOperation() {
    public String apply() {
        return "lazy result";
    }
};

op.apply(); // Nothing actually happens until this step.
```

### Bitwise Conditionals

Now that we have a way to create chunks of code that can be executed in a delayed manner, we need a way to choose between them. Java's type safety is normally a good thing, but it gets in the way here. So first, some tools to do comparisons that yield an int instead of a boolean (this will be important in a moment).

First we define `#isNegative` by extracting the sign bit. We can do this because we know that Java stores ints in 2's complement, so the highest bit contains 1 if the int is negative and 0 if the int is positive.

Note that this returns 0 when passed 0.

```
private static int isNegative(int n) {
    return n >> (Integer.SIZE - 1) & 1;
}
```

Once we have that, `#isPositive` is trivial, but we want it because it makes the logic easier to understand later on.

Note that this also returns 0 when passed 0.

```
private static int isPositive(int n) {
    return isNegative(-n);
}
```

Lastly, we need a check for zero, which involves checking if the int is positive or negative, then flipping all of the bits (the `~` operation) and extracting the lowest to get 1 or 0.

```
private static int isZero(int n) {
    return ~(isPositive(n) | isNegative(n)) & 1;
}
```

This allows us to create the function we really need, but which would be really, really hard to follow if we in-lined the above logic.

This function acts as a filter, passing 0 unless the following rules hold:

1. n is positive
2. the difference between max and n is non-negative

Basically, we're looking for valid input for the recursion to continue.

```
private static int shouldRecurse(int n, int max) {
    int difference = max - n;
    return isPositive(n) & (isPositive(difference) | isZero(difference));
}
```

### Abstractions

Now it's time to start putting things together. There are two helpers we are going to create that are conceptually similar to common helpers in functional programming: `#foldRight` and `#foldLeft`.

We'll also need one new interface.

```
private interface IntToString {
    String apply(int n);
}

public static String foldRight(int times, IntToString function) {
    return (new LazyStringOperation[]{
        new LazyStringOperation() {
            public String apply() {
                return "";
            }
        },
        new LazyStringOperation() {
            public String apply() {
                return foldRight(times - 1, function) + function.apply(times - 1);
            }
        }
    })[shouldRecurse(times, DAYS_OF_CHRISTMAS)].apply();
}

public static String foldLeft(int times, IntToString function) {
    return (new LazyStringOperation[]{
        new LazyStringOperation() {
            public String apply() {
                return "";
            }
        },
        new LazyStringOperation() {
            public String apply() {
                return function.apply(times - 1) + foldLeft(times - 1, function);
            }
        }
    })[shouldRecurse(times, DAYS_OF_CHRISTMAS)].apply();
}
```

You've probably noticed they are very close to identical. Actually, the only difference between them is that the combination is done either before or after the recursive call. This is more important than you'd think (deals with avoiding StackOverflow by using tail-recursion), but is a bit out of scope here.

The actual recursive operation is achieved by creating an array of lazy operations, with the base case at index 0, and the recursive case at index 1. It's a common convention to make the base case return an identity value, in the case of strings that is `""`. As you can see, this simplifies the logic nicely.

After creating the array, we immediately index into it using our decision function, which we know only yields 0 or 1. We then call `LazyOperation#apply` to execute the operation. This is nice because our decision function will avoid out of bounds input by jumping directly to the base case (which does not access the array).

### Putting it all together

There are other minor improvements, mostly consolidating logic, and some minor modification of the way indexes are passed to account for having a base case that doesn't access the array.

```
public class TwelveDaysOfChristmas {
    private static final int DAYS_OF_CHRISTMAS = 12;
    private static final String[] presents = new String[] {
        "A partridge in a pear tree",
        "Two turtle doves and",
        "Three French Hens,",
        "Four calling birds",
        "Five golden rings.",
        "Six geese a-laying,",
        "Seven swans a-swimming,",
        "Eight maids a-milking,",
        "Nine ladies dancing,",
        "Ten lords a-leaping,",
        "Eleven Pipers piping,",
        "Twelve drummers drumming,"
    };

    private static final String[] ordinalNumbers = new String[] {
        "first",
        "second",
        "third",
        "fourth",
        "fifth",
        "sixth",
        "seventh",
        "eighth",
        "ninth",
        "tenth",
        "eleventh",
        "twelfth"
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print(foldRight(
            DAYS_OF_CHRISTMAS,
            new IntToString() {
                public String apply(int n) {
                    return verse(n);
                }
            }));
    }

    private interface IntToString {
        String apply(int n);
    }

    private interface LazyStringOperation {
        String apply ();
    }

    private static int isNegative(int n) {
        return n >> (Integer.SIZE - 1) & 1;
    }

    private static int isPositive(int n) {
        return isNegative(-n);
    }

    private static int isZero(int n) {
        return ~(isPositive(n) | isNegative(n)) & 1;
    }

    private static int shouldRecurse(int n, int max) {
        int difference = max - n;
        return isPositive(n) & (isPositive(difference) | isZero(difference));
    }

    private static String foldRight(int times, IntToString function) {
        return (new LazyStringOperation[]{
            new LazyStringOperation() {
                public String apply() {
                    return "";
                }
            },
            new LazyStringOperation() {
                public String apply() {
                    return foldRight(times - 1, function) + function.apply(times - 1);
                }
            }
        })[shouldRecurse(times, DAYS_OF_CHRISTMAS)].apply();
    }

    private static String foldLeft(int times, IntToString function) {
        return (new LazyStringOperation[]{
            new LazyStringOperation() {
                public String apply() {
                    return "";
                }
            },
            new LazyStringOperation() {
                public String apply() {
                    return function.apply(times - 1) + foldLeft(times - 1, function);
                }
            }
        })[shouldRecurse(times, DAYS_OF_CHRISTMAS)].apply();
    }

    private static String verse(int verseNumber) {
        return leadIn(verseNumber)
            + foldLeft(verseNumber + 1, new IntToString() {
                    public String apply(int n) {
                        return presents[n] + '\n';
                    }
                })
            + '\n';
    }

    private static String leadIn(int verseNumber) {
        return String.format("On the %s day of Christmas,\nMy true love sent to me\n",
                             ordinalNumbers[verseNumber]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! You have presented an alternative solution, but haven't reviewed the code. Please explain your reasoning (how your solution works and how it improves upon the original) so that the author can learn from your thought process.

Comment: My bad, I though the extensive comments on what I was doing, and why, made both the technique for avoid using exceptions for branching and the other improvements clear and understandable. I'll expand them later today, as I've improved it a bit since then.

Comment: Ah, I had missed the explanations in your comments. It's recommended that you don't use comments in the code to explain your suggestions. It's easy to miss, as I've just shown haha. People often answer by splitting up the code and having normal text between each code block to explain it.

Comment: Generics is introduced in Java 5. :)

Comment: This probably violates the "only static methods" rule, though.

Comment: @PetrHudeček Possibly, but it was the best way I could find around using exceptions for branch control. The other involved unrolling the recursion into 12 separate static methods that call each other in a chain ;) Without knowing the professor, there's no way to be 100% sure. I'm hoping that the OP will update the question with feedback from the professor. I'd hate to think they intended to teach exceptions as an acceptable form of flow control.

Comment: +1 for avoiding use try/catch in place of conditionals (which is really just a hacky way of doing a conditional anyhow.)  This to me is the only valid answer.  (Smac89's would be also if Java 8 were allowed.)

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you are allowed to use Java 8 streams, then you can accomplish this.

The [IntStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) deals with generating integers on the fly. Of particular interest to you would be the `range` static methods of this class which provide a way of generating a range of values with a start and end value as parameters.

This allows you to do `IntStream.range(0, 12)`

By doing this, you have just found a work around to using the `try-catch` blocks. Now how to use this?

Well probing deeper into the heart of the stream API's, they each seem to implement another method called `mapToObj`, which (if you can picture this) takes a type supplied by the current stream and "maps" those values to a function which takes object of the supplying stream and produces objects of another type (specified by the function's return type). Thanks to Java 8, we can satisfy this function requirement by supplying a function we have declared in the current class.

This gets you to this:

```
IntStream.range(0, 12)
    .mapToObj(TwelveDaysOfChristmas::versesBelow)
```

Now we have satisfied the recursion problem, and finally we can "collect" the results into a string by making use of another class of Streams called [Collector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html)s

This gets us here:

```
IntStream.range(0, 12)
    .mapToObj(TwelveDaysOfChristmas::versesBelow)
    .collect(Collectors.joining("\n\n"));
```

Moving on, it is time to actually do some work. Notice that we call the method `versesBelow` with an integer which represents the current day we are on. So in this method the first thing we want to print is the `verseText` formatted with the day, and finally the gifts received from day 1 to this day, but backwards.

You already know how to format a string using `String.format` method, so we will leave that, now inside this format method, we want to pass the day we are on, but print the gifts received backwards starting with the current day till day 1. We make use another `IntStream`,

```
String.format(verseText, days[day],
    IntStream.rangeClosed(0, day)
```

To make it appear as if the stream is backwards, you pipe this input to another stream which does the reversing

```
String.format(verseText, days[day],
    IntStream.rangeClosed(0, day)
        .map(i -> day - i)
```

Next we grab each line and collect that into a string with a newline seperating them:

```
String.format(verseText, days[day],
    IntStream.rangeClosed(0, day)
        .map(i -> day - i)
        .mapToObj(i -> lines[i])
        .collect(Collectors.joining("\n")));
```

Putting it all together:

```
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class TwelveDaysOfChristmas {

    public static final String[] lines = new String[] {
            "A partridge in a pear tree",
            "Two turtle doves and",
            "Three French Hens,",
            "Four calling birds",
            "Five golden rings.",
            "Six geese a-laying,",
            "Seven swans a-swimming,",
            "Eight maids a-milking,",
            "Nine ladies dancing,",
            "Ten lords a-leaping,",
            "Eleven Pipers piping,",
            "Twelve drummers drumming,"
    };

    public static final String[] days = new String[] {
            "first",
            "second",
            "third",
            "fourth",
            "fifth",
            "sixth",
            "seventh",
            "eighth",
            "ninth",
            "tenth",
            "eleventh",
            "twelfth"
    };

    public static final String verseText = "On the %s day of Christmas,\n" +
            "My true love sent to me\n%s";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Print the song
        System.out.println(song());
    }

    public static String song() {
        //The song consists of all verses up to verse 12, but the index starts from 0
        //Print verses 0 to 11
        return IntStream.range(0, 12)
                .mapToObj(TwelveDaysOfChristmas::versesBelow)
                .collect(Collectors.joining("\n\n"));
    }

    public static String versesBelow(int day) {

        return String.format(verseText, days[day],
                IntStream.rangeClosed(0, day)
                    .map(i -> day - i)
                    .mapToObj(i -> lines[i])
                    .collect(Collectors.joining("\n")));
    }
}
```

Comment: Using a stream is similar to using a for-loop. I considered that too... and decided it was a cheat, but, that just goes to show that this sort of question is bad for code review... it's not looking to apply best practices.

Comment: @rolfl, I will leave that decision up to the OP. I have never seen what the java stream methods look like (internally) nor do I care what they look like. All I was concerned with when writing this was not using conditionals or loops

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but my school only has a Java 5 compiler :)